# JWT - "invalid signature" in expressJS (jsonwebtoken)

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

We have a system that generate a token using java:

```
private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return Jwts.builder()
            .setClaims(claims)
            .setSubject(subject)
            .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWT_EXPIRATION * 1000))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret).compact();
}
```

I'm trying to verify this token in a ExpressJS App but everytime it run give us an invalid signature. I've already trying use the secret with base64 or only string but nothing works.
The thing is if the java code is change to **secret.getBytes("UTF-8")** the validation works, but this is not something I can do because others apps work just fine with the current token.

Here is the code in the express, this is my first work with node so I'm not entirely familiar with. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function verifyJWT(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.query['auth'];

    if (!token) return res.status(401).send({ auth: false, message: 'No token provided.' });


    //encoding
    let secret64 = Buffer.from(secret, 'ascii').toString("base64");
    let secretBase64 = Buffer.from(secret, "base64");
 
    jwt.verify(token, secret, { algorithms: 'HS512' }, function (err, decoded) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log("MESSAGE: " + err.message);
            return res.status(500).send({ auth: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
        }


        // if ok save to request
        req.userId = decoded.id;
        next();
    });
}

app.get('/testjwt', verifyJWT, function (req, res) {
    res.send('IT WORKS')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the buffer, you are telling it the string should be interpreted as bytes of ASCII.

Probably just create a buffer of UTF-8 bytes instead?

```
Buffer.from(secret, "utf8")
```

So, all together:

```
let secret64 = Buffer.from(secret, "utf8").toString("base64");
```

Comment: Hi, yeah I tried that and utf-8 but it didn't work either